# Dynamo db: Not able to fetch two columns with filterExpression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to aws dynamodb so pardon for any silly mistake. I was trying to fetch two columns from my Activity table. Also I wanted to fetch only those columns where partition key starts with some specific string. Partition key has format activity_EnrolledStudentName.(e.g Dance_studentName) So I wanted to fetch all those items from table where activity is Dance. I was trying to use the following query:

```
public List<StudentDomain> getAllStudents(String activity) {
    List<StudentDomain> scanResult = null;
    DynamoDBUtil dynamoDBUtil = new DynamoDBUtil();
    AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient = dynamoDBUtil.getDynamoDBClient();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
    scanExpression.withProjectionExpression("studentId, ActivitySkills")
    .addFilterCondition(STUDENT_PRIMARY_KEY,
            new 
    Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.BEGINS_WITH)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new 
    AttributeValue().withS(activity)));
    scanResult = mapper.scan(StudentDomain.class, scanExpression);
    return scanResult;
```

However I am getting the following error when i executed above query.

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {ScanFilter} Expression parameters: {ProjectionExpression} (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: TMS27PABBC2BS3UU7LID731G0FVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

Can anyone please suggest where I am mistaken and which other query shall i use otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve but if I understood correctly then you don't need a scan operation for that which actually scans the whole table and afterwords filter the result.

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("TableName");

QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("studentId = : ActivitySkills")

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
Item item = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   item = iterator.next();
   System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
}
```

The filter expression you are using are intented to be used as a filter for secondary attributes and not the range or partition keys. At least this is my interpretation of the documentation

Please read the query documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html